# Many to Many with Same Object using Link Object in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm quite new to EF but I have what I would have thought is quite a common situation In that I have an object called course and object called RelatedCourse which is a many to many relationship modeled with a Link Table. Originally I tried to make this two way relationship (so either courseID could indicate the relationship) but that seemed over complicated whilst I'm learning so settled on getting it working one way.   My code (other properties taken out for simplicity) is below:

Course Class:

```
[Table("Course")]
public class Course : BaseEntity
{
//PRIMARY PROPERTIES
public int CourseId { get; set; }
public string CourseCode { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

//NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
public ICollection<RelatedCourse> RelatedCourses { get; set; }
}
```

RelatedCourse Class:

```
[Table("CourseRelated")]
public class RelatedCourse : BaseEntity
{
    #region Public Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public int RelatedCourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public virtual Course CourseRelated { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}
```

Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
//Course
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasKey(s => s.CourseId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
.HasMany(c => c.RelatedCourses)
.WithOne(c => c.Course)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.CourseId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

//Related Courses
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedCourse>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedCourse>()
.HasOne(c => c.Course)
.WithMany(c => c.RelatedCourses);
```

Repository:

```
public Course CourseGetRelationshipsFromCode(string courseCode)
    {
        return _context.Courses
            .Where(t => t.CourseCode == courseCode && t.DateDeleted == null)
            .Include(t => t.RelatedCourses)
            .Single();
    }
```

When I call "CourseGetRelationshipsFromCode"  it does work, but in my RelatedCourses Property on "Course" I have a populated "Course" which is the course I'm getting from the CourseCode which I don't really need and null in my CourseRelated Object which should be the Course which is related to the one I'm looking at, and I can't understand how to make that work.

Can someone please advise how to fix this and if there is way not to return "Course" as part of "RelatedCourse" as it seems a bit pointless to me.

Comment: It's seems like you have duplicated properties in RelatedCourse: CourseId & RelatedCourseId

Comment: In your model, you are trying to use navigation `RelatedCourses` in 2 different relationship, which does not work. Every navigation can participate in only 1 relationship. 
Can you elaborate more what is the model are you trying to build?

Comment: Its very basic principle really best explained in database language, Say I have Course1, Course2, Course3 in my course table.   Then I want to be able to relate Course1 to Course 2 for example with this relationship being in a CourseRelated table.   So when I view Course1, on my website I can show a list of courses which are related (eg Course2 in this case)